# Is there an anonymous call of a method in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

This is my database manager class:

```
class DatabaseManager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('artist.db')
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()

    def create_table(self):
        self.c.execute(
            'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS artists(title TEXT, artist TEXT, album TEXT, year INTEGER, '
            'genre TEXT, ext TEXT, path TEXT, art TEXT )')
        self.c.close()
        self.conn.close()

    def insert(self, song):
        self.c.execute(
            'INSERT INTO artists(title, artist, album, year, genre, ext, path, art) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
            (song.title, song.artist, song.album, song.year, song.genre, song.ext, song.path, song.art))
        self.conn.commit()
        self.c.close()
        self.conn.close()

    def retrieve_all(self):
        self.c.execute('SELECT * FROM artists')
        data = self.c.fetchall()
        self.c.close()
        self.conn.close()
        return data
```

There are more methods but this is not important. When i start the app i call `create_table()` and when i need some database action i create another obect(or remake the past one) to call `insert` for example.

```
    db = DatabaseManager()
    print(db.retrieve_artist('asdf'))
    db = DatabaseManager()
    print(db.retrieve_all())
```

Is there any way to avoid this? In Java there is anonymous calls:
`new DatabaseManager().retrieve_artist("asdf")`
Is anything similar possible in Python?

Comment: Check for `lamda` functions in python

Comment: How is what you are doing in Java different from the Python? You can of course skip the variable trivially, `DatabaseManager().retrieve_artist('asdf')`.

Comment: Though it's a very strange API, creating an object opens a connection, calling a method on it closes it so you can't use the object anymore. Why?

Comment: cause i am calling the method in different places and classes. Also this will not be used often in code so i prefer not to keep the object when its not needed.

Comment: But it'd be easier to have them as three separate functions that just open and close the connection, instead of this strange class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Remcogerlich said, you are assigning the instantiation to a variable. If you just don't do so, you can approach what you want.

```
DatabaseManager().retrieve_artist('asdf')

AnyOtherClass().callAnyMethod()

# both disappeared
```

In this way, Python executes the instantiation, calls the method you want to, and since you don't tell it to assign to any variable, it "*disappears*".

You may even do that with class functions, like this:

```
ClassWithClassMethods.callAnyClassMethod()
```

However, I wouldn't recommend you to work with that on that way. Normally, database connections are established as an instantiation, used as long as you need to, and when you don't need them anymore you close them *safely*. I think you are not doing that there, and are wasting memory usage, I guess (anyone correct me if I'm wrong). It's easier that you create an object for each time you want to use the database for long, and once you finish in that piece of code, you close the connection and remove the object.

Comment: Why am i wasting memory when i dont keep the object?

Comment: You are wasting memory by creating a instance each time you want to make a database action, because you have to create and close a new connection each time. @nephilimrising

Comment: So you think as @RemcoGerlich suggested to create a method for open and close and call open on App start and close when done?

Comment: @nephilimrising